# cardinality aggregation within filter aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to get count of distinct values using cardinality aggregration.

here is my query

```
{
    "size": 100,
    "_source":["awardeeName"],
    "query": {
        "match_phrase":{"awardeeName" :"The President and Fellows of Harvard College" }  
    },
    "aggs":{
        "awardeeName": {
            "filter" : { "query": { "match_phrase":{"awardeeName" :"The President and Fellows of Harvard College" }}},
            "aggs": {
                "distinct":{"cardinality":{  "field": "awardeeName"}}
           }
        }

    }               
}
```

query using match_phrase for  some text, aggregation with the same match phrase and then call cardinality,
The result, hits count and aggregation fitler match but cardinality shows a different number surprisingly larger than filter and total hits, here is the result

```
  {
    "took": 37,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 3,
        "max_score": 13.516766,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "development",
                "_type": "document",
                "_id": "140a3f5b-e876-4542-b16d-56c3c5ae0e58",
                "_score": 13.516766,
                "_source": {
                    "awardeeName": "The President and Fellows of Harvard College"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "development",
                "_type": "document",
                "_id": "5c668b06-c612-4349-8735-2a79ee2bb55e",
                "_score": 12.913888,
                "_source": {
                    "awardeeName": "The President and Fellows of Harvard College"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "development",
                "_type": "document",
                "_id": "a9560519-1b2a-4e64-b85f-4645a41d5810",
                "_score": 12.913888,
                "_source": {
                    "awardeeName": "The President and Fellows of Harvard College"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "awardeeName": {
            "doc_count": 3,
            "distinct": {
                "value": 7
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expect cardinality to apply on the results of filter, but  in this case   cardinality shows 7 , why is it showing 7 ? How can distinct values  count exceed total hits count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cardinality` aggregation on the `awardeeName` field is counting the number of distinct tokens present on that field for all matching documents.

In your case, in the three matching documents, the `awardeeName` field contains the exact same value `The President and Fellows of Harvard College` which features exactly 7 tokens, hence the result of 7 you see.

What you probably want to achieve is to count `The President and Fellows of Harvard College` as a single token and for that you need a [`keyword` field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html) (instead of a `text` one) and use that field in your `cardinality` aggregation.

Comment: keyword will return 0 records in case  of  match query for value 'college', I want to search both by match and match_phrase, keeping the datatype  text, is there any way to count distinct field values?

Comment: also one other  way my be to map  this property as two different fields, one for full text search with text analyzer and other for distinct count  etc with keyword analyzer?

Comment: That's correct, you probably need a multi-field, i.e. a field for full-text search and another sub-field with keyword analyzer.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
GET calserver-2021.04.1*/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "method.keyword": "searchUser"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "statusCode": "500"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "username_count": {
      "cardinality": {
        "field": "username.keyword",
        "precision_threshold": 40000
      }
    }
  }
}
```